# How to set Routing in AngularJS to work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, runtime-error, url-routing

I have a problem with Routing in AngularJS. I use version 1.6.x and the latest version of angular.route.min.js file.

When I click the button which should take me to the other view, nothing happens. When searching for answer I found out that Routing in AngularJS doesn't work without node.js server. So I installed it and tried to run my application.

Here came the problem; I don't know how to launch this application on node.js. In CMD on Windows I typed : "node index.html" and I got error. The same is with "node app.js" - my javascript source code file.

I attached screenshots to my source code. If anyone could help me it would be great :-).

Thanks in advance.

[My app.js source code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrbsC.png)

[My groceryList html file where I have a button to addItem.html view file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82hXq.png)

Comment: Are you using ng-view in your html? If not try this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: @Raj Yes I am using ng-view on my <div> element like : `<div ng-view></div>`. I still don't know where in my code was mistake but I already solve that by taking further lesson source code of course I was attending. Thanks anyway for help :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Raj's comment seems right on.
You don't have a good screenshot of all of your code, but I think that you are missing the `<div ng-view></div>` aspect from your main view.

I made a plunker example out of your code to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/kB6ETz?p=preview